# How to show discounted products in virtuemart?

Tags: joomla-2.5, module, virtuemart

I've searched a lot and just found [jxct virtuemart product wall](http://www.joomlaxtc.com/support/joomla-guides/921-modules/893-virtuemart-product-wall), but this module is somehow old (last relaese 2012) and has bugs.
I went deep into this module and saw that its uses `$calculator->getProductPrices($item -> id);` and This code caused `getProductPrices no object given query time` error. Instead of passing `$item->id`, I passed `$item` and solved the aforementioned Error.

But the problem is that the `productPrices` array contains only **basePrice**, so this module cannot show other price fields like **finalPrice**.

I need help to whether solve this module problem, or write simple module to show discounted pro

Answer (score 2):

I think VM default module is providing this features,

There is a default module called VM Featured Products.

When you check the module manager option you will be able to sort out there is an option to select only Sale products.

I hope you're using VM2.x.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Discounted Products are different from featured Products, because you can set limited time for discounted products, but I think there is no way to automatically unFeature a product at a specific time.